# Database auto update after commit in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, struts2

I have a website to get survey from employee of a company using Struts2 and Hibernate, MySQL, using Tomcat 6 server. This is method to get question of an event, **the question of event is using UTF-8 encoding**. This is my code:

```
public String getEventQuestion() {
          try {
                 event = surveyEventController.getEvent(this.getId());
                 surveyQuestions = surveyQuestionController.getQuestion(this.getId());
                 if (surveyQuestions != null) {
                       return Constants.SUCCESS;
                 } else {
                       return Constants.FAIL;
                 }
          } catch (Exception e) {
                 logger.error("[Exception]getSurvey: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                 return Constants.FAIL;
          }
   }
```

getQuestion method from controller:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public List<SurveyQuestion> getQuestion(Long eventID)
   {
          Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
          List<SurveyQuestion> listQuestion = null;
          try
          {
                 session.getTransaction().begin(); 

                 listQuestion = (List<SurveyQuestion>)session.createQuery("from SurveyQuestion where event_id="+eventID.toString()).list();
          session.getTransaction().commit();
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
                 logger.error("[Exception] getQuestion SurveyQuestion: ",e);
          session.getTransaction().rollback();
          }
          if(listQuestion!=null && !listQuestion.isEmpty())
          {
                 return listQuestion;
          }
          else
          {
                 return null;
          }
   }
```

All the jsp page encoding is UTF-8 also.

On the first time I access website, the content is successfully loaded with UTF-8 content as I expect.

The problem is after I press F5 to refresh the page, **the content is automatically changed to non UTF-8 encoding**. I debug and recognize that when the line session.getTransaction().commit() is run, the database automatically update with the **listQuestion in non-UTF-8 encoding content**, maybe ISO or something like that, all special character is changed to ?. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is the database?

Comment: @Roman:MySQL, I have set the db encoding to UTF-8. It works perfect on first load, problem appears on pressing F5:(

Comment: What is the page encoding of your JSPs?

Comment: UTF-8 also. At the beginning, page encode is ISO and the content is load not as I expect, then I config all things to UTF-8 encoding, so that page was loaded perfectly, but only on first time load.

Comment: Tomcat 6.0 Roman, sorry for the lack of information:(

Comment: What is the encoding set to the server?

Comment: UTF-8 also. I meant I config every using UTF-8, and it can work ok, but I dont know why the database is automatically updated with wrong content after the commit()

Comment: May be you didn't configure it properly, i.e. parameters passed in the url aren't UTF-8 encoded. By default it's ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that I can define character encoding by

```
<property name="connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/survey?useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8;
    </property>
```

But when the above does not work, I found another solution, in hibernate.cfg.xml, you must define the hibernate character encoding by

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
```

It works properly. Thanks for your support Roman C.